# InvalidArgumentError: -1 is not between 0 and 3

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have compiled the following model.

```
_________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input1 (InputLayer)             (None, 2, 128)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input2 (InputLayer)             (None, 2, 128)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
selfattnlayer1 (SelfAttn)       (None, 2, 128)       49152       input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
selfattnlayer2 (SelfAttn)       (None, 2, 128)       49152       input2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_24 (Lambda)              (None, 2, 768)       0           input1[0][0]                     
                                                                 input2[0][0]                     
                                                                 selfattnlayer1[0][0]             
                                                                 selfattnlayer2[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_lstm (GRU)              (None, 2, 256)       787200      lambda_24[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_18 (TimeDistri (None, 2, 3)         771         encoder_lstm[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 886,275
Trainable params: 886,275
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 1350 samples, validate on 150 samples
Epoch 1/10
```

However, I'm getting the error while fitting the data.

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-04168b02e9ca> in <module>
      5 y=np.array([[1,0,1] for _ in range(1500)])
      6 
----> 7 decomp.fit(X,y)

<ipython-input-86-74a9247c4023> in fit(self, X, y, entails)
     76 
     77 
---> 78         self.model.fit(x=[xg,xe], y=np.expand_dims(y, axis=1), validation_split = 0.1,batch_size=self.batch_size , epochs= self.epochs)

~/ckm/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1637           initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1638           steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1639           validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1640 
   1641   def evaluate(self,

~/ckm/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    213           ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    214 
--> 215         outs = f(ins_batch)
    216         if not isinstance(outs, list):
    217           outs = [outs]

~/ckm/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2984 
   2985     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 2986                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2987     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   2988     return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]

~/ckm/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/ckm/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: -1 is not between 0 and 3
     [[{{node training_11/RMSprop/gradients/selfattnlayer2_6/transpose_2_grad/InvertPermutation}} = InvertPermutation[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@training_11/RMSprop/gradients/selfattnlayer2_6/transpose_2_grad/transpose"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](selfattnlayer2_6/transpose_2/perm)]]
```

Data I'm feeding is

```
decomp = DecomposableAttention()
d1 = np.random.randint(0,10, size=[1500,2,128])
d2 = np.random.randint(0,4, size=[1500,2,128])
X=np.array([d1,d2])
y=np.array([[1,0,1] for _ in range(1500)])

decomp.fit(X,y)
```

Can anybody point me where to look for the error? If need be, I'll share the code (right now, the code is split in 3 files, that's why I've not attached the files). The problem I'm trying to solve is multilabel classification problem using some sort of self-attention.

**Edit:**
I found the error.

```
K.permute_dimensions(K.dot(x, self.WK),(0,-1,1))
```

is offending line. We can not use `-1` while specifying dims. But use only positive integers like so:

```
K.permute_dimensions(K.dot(x, self.WK),(0,2,1))
```

Comment: The problem is likely to be in your custom loss function of `self.myLoss` which you haven't shared. Also, it might be better to share the code of `SelfAttn` as well.

Comment: I was debugging since I posted the code. I removed one layer a time and now it seems the bug is in `SelfAttn` layer. I'll check it and see if I can figure out why the error is popping up?

Comment: @user1190882 I found the bug and posted the solution above. Do you know why negative values like specifying -1 to refer to last dim is illegal?

Answer (score 0):

`permute_dimensions` basically refer to the ordering of your axis. So you have to specify all the axis in which order you wish to get it generated.

You may be getting confused with operations like `reshape` where you can specify one axis as -1. In those operations, it refers to that you wish the TensorFlow to implicitly evaluate the dimension for you.

Comment: Isn't that inconsistency that tf is unable to evaluate dims?